# Why is 3 >> 32 equal to 3?

Tags: java, node.js, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

> why 3 right shift 32 is equal to 3 and not 0.

**I got these results in nodeJs and Java**

- 3 >> 31 = 0
- 3 >> 32 = 3
- 3 >> 33 = 1
- 3 >> 34 = 0
- 3 >> 35 = 0

Comment: C++ is not NodeJs and Java.

Comment: That's undefined behavior.

Comment: There is no runtime check of shift value and shifting with a value larger than 32 depends on the processor behavior. So for the language, it is undefined behavior. Most probably, there is only 5 bits in the instruction field to specify the shift and only the 5 LSB of shift value are kept. So >>32 is equivalent to >>0, >>33 is equivalent to >>1 and so on.

Comment: Same for shift to left n<<32 === n

Comment: It looks like some cyclic shift: length of int32 is 32. So for shif greater than or equals to 32 something like this is happens: val >> (shift % 32). For 32 it will be 0 and 3 >> 0 = 3, for 33 the shift will be 33 % 32 = 1 -> 3 >> 1 = 1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is part of the Java language specification. The right hand operand is wrapped so that it is always in the range 0 - *bits*, where *bits* is the number of bits of the left hand operand. Since you are shifting a 32 bit integer, the right hand operand is wrapped within 0 to 31. 32 becomes 0, 33 becomes 1 etc.

See the [Java language specification for shift operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19):

> If the promoted type of the left-hand operand is int, only the five lowest-order bits of the right-hand operand are used as the shift distance. It is as if the right-hand operand were subjected to a bitwise logical AND operator & (§15.22.1) with the mask value 0x1f (0b11111). The shift distance actually used is therefore always in the range 0 to 31, inclusive.